# How to pass a globbing pattern as parameter to a function in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, solaris, wildcards

I have a assignment in which I am passing a file pattern to a function as below:

```
line=FILE*.txt
getFlag $line
```

While the function is as below:

```
function getFlag
{
    filepattern=$1
    echo "File pattern is: $filepattern"
}
```

I need the output as

```
File pattern is: FILE*.txt
```

While I am getting output as a matching file name present in the folder as below:

```
File pattern is: FILE123.txt
```

Though I am passing a file pattern as a variable to the function it does not prevent variable expansion and the file name matching with the pattern in variable is getting passed.

Any help upon above much appreciated.

Comment: [Always use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to avoid [common pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) (esp. #2)

Comment: @ilkkachu none of your solution is working on my **sparc-sun-solaris2.10** environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [ilkkachu said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317946/how-to-pass-a-regular-expression-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-bash#comment558732_317946), you could single- or double-quote the argument that you're passing to this function:

`line='FILE*.txt'`

or

`line="FILE*.txt"`

Those tell Bash to perform *no* substitution or *some* substitution without doing filename expansion, respectively.

Another option would be to escape the `*` when setting line, then pass the argument to the function using quotes:

```
line=FILE\*.txt
getFlag "$line"
```

Comment: It's the `getFlag $line` command that expands (and globs) the variable and needs the quotes. The assignment itself doesn't actually expand, but it's not a bad habit to use quotes there too, since almost all other contexts will expand (and glob) the variable. compare `foo=*; echo "$foo"` with `foo="*"; echo $foo`.

Comment: @ilkkachu even if I am doing getFlag "$line" or getFlag '$line', it still expands